# ASCII codec can't decode byte 0xc3

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am using Python-2.7 and PyShp to handle GIS data (which is imported as a list of lists). I developed a python script that filters out data using user input as criteria for the filtering. This works fine with the file I used to develope the script. Now that I want to use another file I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I get this right, that is due to an encoding error with ASCII. However my header states "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-". Why is it using ASCII then? As it works with the other file, I assume there is a way to tell python to use utf-8 during the import process. My import line (using PyShp) looks like this:

```
sf = shapefile.Reader(pfad)
```

Whereas "pfad" is pfad = input("Question?"), so user input. Works fine with the other file. What is causing the ASCII error and why does it not use utf-8?

Edit: Here is the original code from PyShp to read shapefile data:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.shp = None
    self.shx = None
    self.dbf = None
    self.shapeName = "Not specified"
    self._offsets = []
    self.shpLength = None
    self.numRecords = None
    self.fields = []
    self.__dbfHdrLength = 0
    # See if a shapefile name was passed as an argument
    if len(args) > 0:
        if is_string(args[0]):
            self.load(args[0])
            return
    if "shp" in kwargs.keys():
        if hasattr(kwargs["shp"], "read"):
            self.shp = kwargs["shp"]
            if hasattr(self.shp, "seek"):
                self.shp.seek(0)
        if "shx" in kwargs.keys():
            if hasattr(kwargs["shx"], "read"):
                self.shx = kwargs["shx"]
                if hasattr(self.shx, "seek"):
                    self.shx.seek(0)
    if "dbf" in kwargs.keys():
        if hasattr(kwargs["dbf"], "read"):
            self.dbf = kwargs["dbf"]
            if hasattr(self.dbf, "seek"):
                self.dbf.seek(0)
    if self.shp or self.dbf:        
        self.load()
    else:
        raise ShapefileException("Shapefile Reader requires a shapefile or file-like object.")
```

Edit 2: Added traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2898, in run_code
self.showtraceback()

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1824, in showtraceback
value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1406, in structured_traceback
self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1323, in structured_traceback
self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 644, in structured_traceback
out_list.extend(self._format_list(elist))

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 694, in _format_list
Colors.Normal)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The encoding declaration in your script only applies to the encoding of the source code (of that particular module). It has nothing to do with how input is processed. You have to check PyShp's documentation to find out how to specify the encoding of the input file.

Comment: There is an issue with displaying your incoming data. Please show line #72 from the script, or whole function if possible.

Comment: My script is only 58 lines long. And Line 72 in the PyShp code refers to Python-3.x, which I am not using. The function shouldn't be the problem, as it works with other data.

Comment: @wanderlust The "position 72" in the DecodeError refers to the byte offset, not the line number.

Comment: The stacktrace you posted shows an error while displaying an error stacktrace, so it's hard to say what really causes it. You get this kind or UnicodeDecodeError when mixing non-ascii byte strings with unicode in some way, e.g `"\xc3" + u""`, could be caused by some Exception with an unicode error message.

Comment: As @mata said, there is another error, which cannot be displayed by IPython. Probably your terminal doesn't support Unicode or it isn't configured properly. Try running the code as a script, maybe redirecting STDERR to a file, to see what the original problem is. (Or fix the terminal encoding to see things in IPython.)

Comment: Running it as a script didn't change anything. Same error. I am rather new to Python and don't know how to redirect STDERR into a file. I'll have a look on google though.

Comment: If you're on a *nix-based platform, you should be able to do `python script.py 2> somefile.txt`, and then that file will contain the STDERR output.

Comment: That works on windows. Here is the output, which I don't quite get. `line 14
    print iop
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`
                                                          Which is weird, as iop is a normal string.

Comment: Ok, this is a completely different story. It means you either ran the script with Python 3, or there is a `from __future__ import print_function` statement in the module with the syntax error.